# JSON striing format exception

Tags: android, json

What is the error here? I am not able to parse it to the list.

[image: image 1]

I am trying to get json from this file using jsonUrl.

Please let me know where am i making this mistake.

```
 "recommended":[
      {
         "thumbnail":"http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7390/11919320035_1f6dd4da79_z.jpg",
         "itemname":"Chilli Babycorn",
         "itemtype":"veg",
         "price":"45"
      },
      {
         "thumbnail":"http://res.cloudinary.com/dhdglilcj/image/upload/v1455448132/foodonz/dishes/d7.jpg",
         "itemname":"Honey Chilli Potato",
         "itemtype":"veg",
         "price":"90"
      }
   ],
   "veg starters":[
      {
         "itemname":"Paneer Tikka",
         "itemtype":"veg",
         "price":"110"
      },

      {
         "itemname":"Aloo Tandoori",
         "itemtype":"veg",
         "price":"60"
      }
   ]

}
```

This is the itemsMenus class

Please relate it with the above code.

```
public class ItemsMenu {
    private String thumbnail;
    private String itemname;
    private String price;

    public String getItemtype() {
        return itemtype;
    }

    public void setItemtype(String itemtype) {
        this.itemtype = itemtype;
    }

    private String itemtype;
    private String quantity="0";


    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }



    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getItemname() {
        return itemname;
    }

    public void setItemname(String itemname) {
        this.itemname = itemname;
    }
}
```

Comment: also post your item menu model

Comment: Why are you mixing the JSONArray/JSONObject API and the Gson API?  You only really need Gson here to parse your string and map that to model objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `json` string direct to `List<ItemsMenu>`

```
List<ItemsMenu> list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<ItemsMenu>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert any type of json to write model. As your jsons seems to be simple and doesn't require to use TypeToken. And Further use

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,model.class)
```

You will get the desired list.